# law enforcement: plural or singular?

Tags: word-usage

Is *law enforcement* treated the same way as using *police*, that is, as a plural noun?

Which sentence is correct:

> Law enforcement finds the bodies.

or:

> Law enforcement find the bodies.

Answer (score 3):

When you use the phrase "law enforcement" as a collective noun, you treat it as singular. Police is plural, police officer is singular.

As a side note, if you were looking for a plural, you would have to say "law enforcement agencies".